# Ngrok setup an SSL local tunnel to an existing Vhost

Tags: macos, testing, localhost, ngrok, localtunnel

I'm trying t use Ngrok to create a local tunnel to an SSL Virtual host I have on my local machine, but can't seem to get it to work.

My Vhost works perfectly. The site is https://local.mysite.com

Any of the command I try to use to predefine the pointing url on Ngrok, e.g.

```
./ngrok http -host-header=rewrite local.mysite.com:443
```

or

```
./ngrok http -subdomain=local.mysite.com local.mysite.com:443
```

always seems to return:

> Bad Request
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
>   Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

I get that this is happening because I am trying to access a HTTPS connection via a HTTP call but I can't see alternatives in the ngrok docs.

https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `tls` which is only available in the pro subscription.

If you use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), you can use the [share function](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/) which is free and support https.